# How to enable showing DocumentReference for Firebase on Firefox Console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firefox

When I run the code `console.log(firestore.doc('...'))`

Firefox console shows "Object" but Chrome console shows "DocumentReference" which with more detailed info. Firefox console doesn't specify it as DocumentReference. Is there a way to make this like Chrome console? Screenshots are added for clarity.

Firefox:
[image: Firefox Console]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Firefox doesn't display the result the same way as Chrome. To find the same info as Chrome, click `prototype` :

[image: prototype screenshot from Firefox]

Comment: Yes, that is it, for some reason which I don't know.